# Creat a website counter on dreamweaver cs5

Tags: dreamweaver, counter, flash-cs5

Hello I use dreamweaver cs5 on my website designer it is very good.
But one thing I wanted to kow was how do i create a counter that counts all the different computer id that look at the page.
I have seen loads of ones you can embed but all of them have links to other sites.

If anyone could help it would be ver appreiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search shows that there is many different options out there. Try searching for "hitcounters". The one that stands out to me is: http://www.e-zeeinternet.com/. That one shows a visible image showing the number of hits. If you want to have that is not visable or shows more info try http://www.google.com/analytics/. You will just need to fill out some information and then embed the code into the page (at the location you want). They are simple to setup